# Android back to call activity

Tags: android, android-activity, call, back-stack

In my app i start an call with `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. So this works fine.
But if I'm in a call I don't want to switch back to another app.

Is it posible to prevent, that the back button can be used in the call mode?

If not, how can I switch back from my app to the call screen.

`moveTaskToBack(true)` can't be used because, if the back button is used to go back, it deletes the activity from the back stack.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

I hope someone can help me...
and sorry for my bad English.

Thanks for every answer

Answer (score 0):

You could override activities onBackPressed() method.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
// Do nothing
}
```

But that is definitely not what you should do. An Android user expect to get back to the previous screen. So my strong recommendation is, do not override the back button behavior. Let the user use the back button  and let it work like the user expects the back button should work. You could use the ActionBars Up Navigation instead.

Comment: Is it posible to override a method in the call activity?
I don't think so.

Comment: So you start a Actiivity B by an Intent from Activit A. And you want not that the user can jump Back from Activity B, right?

Comment: Yes.
But Activity B is the standard Android Call Activity.

Comment: Ah, so you call not your own Activity, but Activity B is another apps Activity ...  I see ... So no, there is no way to do so. But why the hell are you trying to achieve such a begavior? You could use a workaround that may work or may not work in your case: You could startActivityForResult() and check the result and react on that (restart by sending the intent again), but overall thats not a good idea :D

Comment: I think if i take a call from my app, a don't do anything else talk to someone and then end the call. I don't want to switch to any other app or activty.

Comment: Hm, as far as I know there is no way to do that. Thats out of your range or controll, since its another app ...

Comment: But isn't it posible to switch to an active activity?

Comment: What do you mean with switch and what is an active activity? The user can use the other started activity like any other. He can press the back button to come back to your activity, he can press the home button, he can press the app switcher (multitasking button). Once more, you can not modificate the started activity. But the most Activities you can be call with startActivityFor result are build in a manner to be more like a "fullscreen dialog" and they should not mislead  the user to do something other (or start another app)  then fullfill this "dialog" or to complete the required action

Comment: I want to bring the call activity back to the front. If i'm in the call activity and press the back button, the call activity will not close and end the call, it switch only to the background... So i think it must be possible to bring it back to the front.

Thx for your help